# How to remove line from m file in MATLAB after its execution

Tags: matlab

I'm stuck in one case related to matlab.

I create a file through script by using these commands:

```
delete output
delete f.m
clc;
% This is a Cell Array!
prompt={'Enter Function f(x) Here :'};...
% Name of the Dialog Box
name='Trapezoidal Rule Input Screen';...
numlines=1;  % Number of lines visible for User Input
% Default Answer
defaultanswer={'1 + exp(-x).*sin(4*x)'};...
% Creating the Dialog box where the User Input is stored into a Cell Array
answer=inputdlg(prompt,name,numlines,defaultanswer);...
global y1
y1=answer{1};...
diary  f.m;
disp('function y = f(x)');...
            %disp('y = '),disp(y),disp(';');...
            %disp('y = ((1+(x^2))^-1);');...
            fprintf('y=%s;\n',y1);
diary off;
f(0);
```

when the click on RUN CHECK button then f.m file had been created because it is part of script and generate the following code in f.m file

```
function y = f(x)
            %disp('y = '),disp(y),disp(';');...
            %disp('y = ((1+(x^2))^-1);');...
            fprintf('y=%s;\n',y1);
y=1 + exp(-x).*sin(4*x);
diary off;
```

but it stop and highlight error that y1 is apparently use before it is define.

```
fprintf('y=%s;\n',y1);
```

so if any 1 have some solution regarding this problem please help me out.

Comment: Why do you create f.m at all?  Why not just do the f.m stuff in your original script?

Comment: Please use the `{}` button in the editor to format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not abuse the diary command for this.

Why not just:

```
fid = fopen('f.m','w');
fprintf(fid,'function y=f(x)\n');
fprintf(fid,'y=%s;\n';
fclose(fid);
```